# Getting closest distance between a square's edge and a point 2D

Tags: 2d

How would I get the closest distance between a square's edge and a point in 2D, if I only have the points coordinates, and the coordinates of the square and it's size?

Comment: Have you tried Google for "distance line to point"? It is a quite common problem that has been solved many times. Since a square is 4 line segments, it should be fairly easy to figure out the closest point. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i know how to do circles, but i count even think of how to do squares.

Answer (score 2):

```
float DistanceFromRectangle(Vector2 point, Vector2 center, Vector2 size, float angle) {

    // First, transform the point into the rectangle's local coordinate space.
    Vector2 offset = Rotate(point - center, -1 * angle);

    // Take the absolute value of this offset, on x and y, and subtract the size.
    // This gives zero on the edge, increasing positively as we move away.
    // Clamp out any values less than zero.
    Vector2 outside = Max(Abs(offset) - size/2, Vector2.zero);

    // Return the length of this vector, which is our distance to the closest point
    // on the square's edges or corners, and zero inside the square.
    return Length(outside);
}
```

Comment: thanks! though could you translate that into math that doesn’t use vectors?

Comment: Repeat everything for x and y and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Felsir and DMGregory, I just googled 'distance point to square' and I found a already existing stackexchange question about this.
[How do I calculate distance between a point and an axis-aligned rectangle?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-a-point-and-an-axis-aligned-rectangle)
Thanks!!

Comment: Next time, search *before* asking. ;) It's a lot faster for everyone involved.

Comment: Sorry, I had looked, but not thoroughly enough.
I'll make sure I can't find anything before asking.